# Windows 7 Explorer Command Bar

Tags: windows, winapi, windows-7, registry, windows-explorer

Is it possible to add a link to my own tool (an .exe file) in the Windows 7 Explorer Command Bar ?

[image]

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Is it possible. Yes? Does it involve a gross hack? Yes. Is there a supported way to do this? No.

Comment: Is there any other way then to add a button easily clickable in Windows 7 Explorer in order to launch a tool (depending of the folder where you are) ?

Comment: Context menu shell extension will do the job

Comment: Do you mean Right click -> Context Menu -> then click on a menu item ?
I'm looking really for a "one"click  button (like in the Windows Explorer Command Bar)

Comment: OK, do it your way then.

Comment: I cannot help you if you want to continue on this path. You are doomed to fail. But it's best that you learn that from experience. Once you've done that, you'll add a context menu item.

Comment: If I have to use a context menu item, my tool is useless (because  freewares that do that already exist), so I will stop trying to code it.
The only interest is if I can access this tool in 1 click.
Thanks for your answers!

Comment: Well, good luck doing it your way.

Comment: Thank you. Maybe you have some litlle hints (you said possible but with gross hack) ?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/39576/discussion-between-jos-bas-and-david-heffernan)

Comment: Inject a DLL into explorer. Make sure no anti-malware software detects that you did that. Reverse engineer the explorer implementation for all Windows versions you target. Add your UI, finding a way to execute code in the UI thread. Make sure you test your uninstaller very well since it will be the most used feature of your software.